# Playbook that runs within the desktop session of a windows host?

Tags: windows, ansible

so I'm trying to automate interactions with an application that requires a window to be opened on the (windows) host.

Right now, I cant seem to find a way to do this. Even with Psexec ran interactively, it still fails to open any window. Lets use this an example, I want to open notepad.exe on the hosts desktop session

```
    - name: Run notepad.exe on the hosts logged in desktop sesion
      win_psexec:
        command: notepad.exe
        interactive: yes
        username: logged_in_user
        password: logged_in_pass
```

Right now in this example, it goes straight to “notepad exited with code 0”

Is there an established way to do this in ansible? I feel this must be a common problem people run into, or maybe I'm just thinking about this wrong. Any help would be appreciated!